# Getting Attribute value in ng-repeat from a Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Well I have my ng repeat like so :

```
<div ng-repeat="X in Xs" ><a id="X.id" my-directive>Blabla {{X.Number}}</a></div>
```

and I Have my Directive like this :

```
module.directive('myDirective', ['$document', function ($document) {
return {
    replace : true,
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {

    element.on('mousedown', function (event) {
        // Prevent default dragging of selected content
        event.preventDefault();
        startX = event.pageX - x;
        startY = event.pageY - y;
        $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
    });

    function mouseup() {
        $document.off('mouseup', mouseup);
        console.log(attr.id);
        scope.DeleteAlert(1); //Function to delete an element from Scope table
    }
}
};
}]);
```

And Actually i can't get the value of "id" and it's returning "X.id" !!

So How can I get the value of my attribute ?

I want to get the id so to pass it like an argument to my function to delete the div in question. Now, I'm passing "1" to my function and that is deleting always the first element of my list.

Can anyone help me figure it out please!!

**UPDATE**

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5P36t/36/) for test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using it in the id, wrap it in {{ just like you do in the contents:

```
<div id="{{Fire.id}}" my-directive>
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5P36t/37/)

Comment: Like magic it's working !!
I don't know why sometimes we should use them without {{ and sometimes we need to wrap them in {{.

Can you explain it to me please ?

Comment: @Ayyoub For *most* of the command prefixed with `ng` (ng-href is an exception for example) you do not have to use the double brackets `{{}}`

Comment: And for ng-click for example when i want to call a function i don't use them neither ng-click="myFunction(Fire.id)" and it's work but wrap it between brackets is not working